# Calling /usr/sbin/installer that fails if there's already another installation

Tags: terminal, install

I'm running the following installation command from auto-script, but it may halt for some time if another installation is currently being made.

`sudo installer -pkg myPkg.pkg -target /`

Perhaps there's an option to instantly quit with error in such case (and I'll decide if I if/when I want to retry) ? in other linux distribution there's a flag called -nointeractive, but it doesn't exist in macOS, is there any substitution ?

Also, there's always the option to first check if another instance of installer is already running using pgrep, but i'd rather avoid this option as it's not prone to race condition.

```
if pgrep -x "installer" > /dev/null
then
    exit 1
else
    sudo /usr/sbin/installer -pkg path/to/package.pkg -target /
fi
```

Comment: What kind of research have you done regarding command options and similar?

Comment: I looked at the man page but couldn't find any suitable flag. Perhaps you can guide me where else to look ?

Comment: If it‘s not in the man page it‘s probably not available as an option.  But if you are open for other solution, you could also just pgrep for a running installer